# Spring Roo Shell in Eclipse: Could not create sts.roo.ui.rooShellView

Tags: eclipse, spring-roo, spring-tool-suite

- **IDE**: springsource-tool-suite-3.6.4.RELEASE-e4.4.2 / eclipse-4.4.2 with sts-3.6.4.201503051146-RELEASE
- **IDE Plugin**:

  - Spring IDE Roo Support v3.6.4.201503051146-RELEASE (via Eclipse Marketplace)
  - Maven project configuration for Eclipse AJDT v0.14.0.201302011330 (via http://dist.springsource.org/release/AJDT/configurator/)
- **Spring Roo**: spring-roo-1.3.1.RELEASE / spring-roo-2.0.0.M1
- **Reproduce Step**:

  - import project created by Spring-Roo into eclipse
  - right click project
  - choose "Spring Tools"
  - click "Open Roo Shell"
  - will see "Could not create the view: com.springsource.sts.roo.ui.rooShellView" this error message in Eclipse "Roo Shell" View.

> How fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/ROO-3633), current version of Spring IDE Roo Support plugin has no support to load Spring Roo version higher than 1.2.1.

This is already fixed in new plugin version that will be released with STS 3.7.0 which is scheduled for end of June/early July.

Until that, you can use STS with Roo running it in system shell.